# Firebase user types

Tags: firebase, analytics, roles, firebase-analytics

I have a project that uses Firebase analytics. I want to assign a user for just viewing analytics Data.

Recently, Google added `Permissions` option that can add user with email address and role, but I could not find out which user is fit for that.
this is adding user progress:
first click permission in project page:

[image]

then select "add user" and then you should enter an email address and role type:

[image]

Is there any documentation that describe these user roles and scopes?

[image]

Comment: Hi. Can you point out where these *Permissions* are visible from? Is it in the Firebase Console or Developers Console?

Comment: @AL. I updated the progress of adding user with images ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the *Learn More* hyperlink visible in the 2nd screenshot you provided, it'll take you to the [Understanding Roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles?hl=en_US&_ga=1.10948724.1710370421.1488348353#curated_roles) documentation that talks about the roles and the permissions.

It seems that there are two types of roles, [Primitive](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#primitive_roles) and [Predefined](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#predefined_roles) (which is still in Beta).

> **Primitive Roles**
>
> Roles that existed prior to Cloud IAM, Owner, Editor, and Viewer will continue to work as they did before. These roles are concentric; that is, the Owner role includes the permissions in the Editor role, and the Editor role includes the permissions in the Viewer role.
>
> **Predefined roles**
>
> <sub>**Beta**: The Beta Cloud IAM roles described in this section might be changed in backward-incompatible ways and are not recommended for production use. They are not subject to any SLA or deprecation policy.</sub>
>
> In addition to the primitive roles, Cloud IAM provides additional predefined roles that give granular access to specific Google Cloud Platform resources and prevent unwanted access to other resources.

The list of roles for each and a description for their permissions are also described there.

Comment: Not entirely familiar with roles. But basing from the descriptions, it's probably `roles/viewer` - *Permissions for read-only actions that preserve state.*